# AS3: How to create a variable that will erase Keys from memory?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, key, animate.css, ibm-doors

I do the game alone, but I do not know how to program at all.

I'm using engine "Edward" ([edward.sophiehoulden.com](http://edward.sophiehoulden.com))

There is a variable that adds "Keys" to the memory for opening "Doors".

```
//## Keys
for (i=0; i<mcLevel.keyArray.length; i++){
    for (k=0; k<keysOwned.length; k++){
        if ( keysOwned[i] == mcLevel.keyArray[i].keyName.text ){
            mcLevel.keyArray[i].visible = false;
        }
    }
    if ( mcLevel.keyArray[i].hitTestObject( mcLevel.mcPlayer.collisionBox ) ){
        keysOwned.push( mcLevel.keyArray[i].keyName.text );
        mcLevel.keyArray[i].visible = false;
    }

}
```

I really need to have a variable with the opposite function.

Many thanks to those who respond.

Comment: _"but I do not know how to program at all"_ You can check the AS3 docs for [**Arrays**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html). Look at description of the method `.push`, then check other methods like `.pop` or `.removeAt` etc etc to see what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to remove a key with the name "myGreatKey":

```
for (i=0; i<keysOwned.length; i++)
{
    if ( keysOwned[i] == "myGreatKey" )
    {
        keysOwned.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```